# PostGIS Error - PG::InternalError: ERROR: could not load library

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, postgis

```
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

PG::InternalError: ERROR:  could not load library "/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.4.5/lib/postgis-2.1.so": dlopen(/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.4.5/lib/postgis-2.1.so, 10): Symbol not found: __ZN5boost7archive21basic_binary_iarchiveINS0_15binary_iarchiveEE13load_overrideERNS0_15class_name_typeEi
  Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/libSFCGAL.1.dylib
  Expected in: /usr/local/lib/libboost_serialization-mt.dylib
 in /usr/local/lib/libSFCGAL.1.dylib
: CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "postgis"/Users/harshamv/Sites/clink/db/migrate/20150812164615_enable_postgis.rb:3:in `change'
-e:1:in `<main>'
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::InternalError: ERROR:  could not load library "/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.4.5/lib/postgis-2.1.so": dlopen(/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.4.5/lib/postgis-2.1.so, 10): Symbol not found: __ZN5boost7archive21basic_binary_iarchiveINS0_15binary_iarchiveEE13load_overrideERNS0_15class_name_typeEi
  Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/libSFCGAL.1.dylib
  Expected in: /usr/local/lib/libboost_serialization-mt.dylib
 in /usr/local/lib/libSFCGAL.1.dylib
: CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "postgis"
/Users/harshamv/Sites/clink/db/migrate/20150812164615_enable_postgis.rb:3:in `change'
-e:1:in `<main>'
PG::InternalError: ERROR:  could not load library "/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.4.5/lib/postgis-2.1.so": dlopen(/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.4.5/lib/postgis-2.1.so, 10): Symbol not found: __ZN5boost7archive21basic_binary_iarchiveINS0_15binary_iarchiveEE13load_overrideERNS0_15class_name_typeEi
  Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/libSFCGAL.1.dylib
  Expected in: /usr/local/lib/libboost_serialization-mt.dylib
 in /usr/local/lib/libSFCGAL.1.dylib
/Users/harshamv/Sites/clink/db/migrate/20150812164615_enable_postgis.rb:3:in `change'
-e:1:in `<main>'
```

Am getting the above error all of sudden when i tried to drop and recreate my Rails-PostgreSQL

Comment: Take a look http://cookieshq.co.uk/posts/introduction-to-postgis-and-rails/

Comment: PostGIS has not been installed correctly. Can you update your question to include how did you install it?

Comment: @Swanand it was the issue of boost as mentioned in the answers.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You probably recently upgraded the `boost` Homebrew formula doing a `brew update` / `brew upgrade`, and it seems the latest version is not playing well with `postgis`.

I fixed a very similar issue by going back to the previous version of `boost` with:

`brew switch boost 1.58.0`

**UPDATE**: now that this was fixed in Homebrew, the answer below suggesting to do a simple update / upgrade is probably the way to go. If you *did* switch previously, you can now `brew switch boost 1.59.0` to upgrade to the latest version of `boost`, you might also have to `brew reinstall postgis`.

Comment: Awesome ! That was my issue ! @Harsha you should accept this answer !

Comment: yes.. boost updated when i did brew update :/ which is the best way to keep things normal but continue getting the latest ?

Comment: My 1.58.0 version is gone and so I get `Error: boost does not have a version "1.58.0" in the Cellar. Versions available: 1.59.0`. How can I get the older version?

Comment: Recovered it from Time Machine backup in `/usr/local/Cellar/boost/`. Your solution worked - thanks! Did anyone raise an issue at PostGIS / boost?

Comment: Does anyone have boost 1.58 available? I'm on a brand new computer and can't get it

Comment: You can use `brew pin boost` to keep boost at a particular version.  `brew unpin boost` returns it for normal upgrades.

Comment: can you update saying that this has been fixed by homebrew. wanna accept this as the answer

Comment: @HarshaMV updated by answer, thanks for the headsup.

Answer (score 5):

This [issue has been fixed here](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/45695). Re-install and it should work.

```
    $ brew update && upgrade
    $ brew install postgis
```

Answer (score 3):

Couldn't find 1.58.0 either, but 1.55.0_1 is available and successfully installed postgis for me. These entries in [effectif](http://effectif.com/mac-os-x/installing-specific-version-of-homebrew-formula) and [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3987683/homebrew-install-specific-version-of-formula/4158763#4158763) were very helpful. The process may have extra steps.

Just to be sure:

```
$ brew uninstall postgis
```

Tap to homebrew versions, if not having it yet:

```
$ brew tap homebrew/versions
```

Find the newest available:

```
$ brew search boost
...
homebrew/versions/boost155
...
$ brew install homebrew/versions/boost155
```

This installs boost under a different formula (`boost155`). To be able to switch versions, I symlinked the old version to the boost directory:

```
$ ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/boost155/1.55.0_1 /usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.55.0_1
```

After this it is business as usual:

```
$ brew switch boost 1.55.0_1
$ brew install postgis
```

Answer (score 2):

If you need to install a specific version of a formula, take a look at this thread:

[Homebrew: install specific version of formula](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3987683/homebrew-install-specific-version-of-formula)

Answer (score 2):

I just ran into this problem as well, and version 1.56.0 of `boost`was available and solved the issue for me. Looks like the problem is specifically with 1.58.0.